# Debugging Mysterious RecyclerView Error that Closes App

Tags: android, debugging, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app with a RecyclerView, and I thought I almost had it running, but ran into a strange error.

I had made a few small changes to correct a small bug, and after that the app would no longer finish setting up the main activity layout.  Instead I got the following screens:

[App closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41mlk.jpg) --- [App keeps closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMD8j.jpg)

My first thought was to look back at my small changes.  But they did not cause this problem.  (Undoing those changes did not fix the problem.)

I now believe that the problem is related to a change in the way the app operates between the first "successful" (though buggy) run and the following runs that fail.

In the first run, the app had to request permission from the user in order to access the documents folder.  But after that, the app no longer needs to ask, because the user has already granted permission.

This means the order of execution has changed prior to the RecyclerView layout being created.  But I can't (yet) figure out what's going wrong or how to fix it.

Here's the OnCreate() method in my main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prog_summary);
}
```

Here's the OnCreate() method & other related methods in the superclass (the class that implements the permissions request):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.state = savedInstanceState;

    if (state != null) {
        isInPermission = state.getBoolean(STATE_IN_PERMISSION, false);
    }

    if (hasAllPermissions(getDesiredPermissions())) {
        onReady(state);
    }
    else if (!isInPermission) {
        isInPermission = true;

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                                    netPermissions(getDesiredPermissions()),
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSION);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int      requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions,
                                       int[]    grantResults) {
    isInPermission = false;

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
        if (hasAllPermissions(getDesiredPermissions())) {
            onReady(state);
        }
        else {
            onPermissionDenied();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the OnReady() method in my activity class (called when permission is granted):

```
@Override
protected void onReady(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    _alEntries = new ArrayList();
    TaskData tdSource = new TaskData();

    // load task item array & trim the excess (unused) ArrayList space
    tdSource.LoadData(this, _alEntries);
    _alEntries.trimToSize();

    // create summary item array & populate it based on task item array
    _alSummaries = new ArrayList();
    PopulateSummaryList();

    _rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvBookList);
    _li = getLayoutInflater();
    _rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    _adapter = new TaskItemAdapter();
    _rv.setAdapter(_adapter);
}
```

The app actually closes when the call to setLayoutManager is executed.  Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong or how to proceed in tracking this down?

Comment: Please post your logcat related to this error.

Comment: Also, you mentioned messing with your layout.  If I had to guess, I would say your _rv variable is null (or it isn't really a RecyclerView) in your onReady method because it couldn't be found in your layout.  Just a guess though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it could be a NullPointerException in that your `_rv` variable is null. Judging by the code it makes sense, your superclass's onCreate method calls onReady() BEFORE setContentView() is called in your subclass's onCreate therefore by the time onReady() is called in your subclass `findViewById(R.id.rvBookList)` will return null as you haven't set the content of the class yet. To fix this I recommend making your superclass an `abstract` class. For example, in your superclass do this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutId());
        this.state = savedInstanceState;

        // ... remaining code from your superclass's onCreate()
    }

    public abstract int getLayoutId();
}
```

Now in your MainActivity, extend BaseActivity. Since BaseActivity is abstract and `getLayoutId()` is an abstract method, it will force you to implement `getLayoutId()` like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.activity_prog_summary;
    }

}
```

Doing this will ensure that all classes that inherit your superclass will perform the correct order of operations, in that setContentView is called before anything else.

Comment: That was it!  Just can't get over how complex & convoluted it is to get permission to read/write to a file in Android...